# hibernate createSqlQuery - escape semicolon on date

Tags: java, hibernate, escaping

I've tried running the following insert native query.

```
queryInsert = "INSERT INTO abc(id,date1, date2) VALUES(5,\"2014-10-20 14:31:01\",\"2014-10-20 14:31:11\");";
SQLQuery sqlQuery = session.createSQLQuery(queryInsert);
sqlQuery.executeUpdate();
```

And I got the following exception:

```
org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not execute statement
    at org.hibernate.exception.internal.SQLStateConversionDelegate.convert(SQLStateConversionDelegate.java:123) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.5.Final.jar:4.3.5.Final]
    ....
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744) [na:1.7.0_45]
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: No value specified for parameter 1
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:1094) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.31.jar:na]
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:997) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.31.jar:na]
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:983) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.31.jar:na]
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:928) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.31.jar:na]
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.checkAllParametersSet(PreparedStatement.java:2487) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.31.jar:na]
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.fillSendPacket(PreparedStatement.java:2462) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.31.jar:na]
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeUpdate(PreparedStatement.java:2311) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.31.jar:na]
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeUpdate(PreparedStatement.java:2262) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.31.jar:na]
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeUpdate(PreparedStatement.java:2246) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.31.jar:na]
    at com.jolbox.bonecp.PreparedStatementHandle.executeUpdate(PreparedStatementHandle.java:205) ~[bonecp-0.8.0.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.executeUpdate(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:187) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.5.Final.jar:4.3.5.Final]
    ... 29 common frames omitted
```

The thing is hibernate is treating the colon (:) in my date string as a query parameter.  What can I do so it will not be treated as a query parameter?  I've tried escaping with \: , and ::, but none works.

Many thanks!

UPDATED:

Thanks for the reply, unfortunately, I can't do the parameterized query on my case.  It is actually more like a dump file with INSERT INTO statements, so splitting them and creating parameterized query would only add overhead, so I just want to run these INSERT INTO query statements.

Comment: use parameters and setParameter

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have just exported some data from postgres database (asking it to create `insert` statements)

The dump looks like

```
INSERT INTO scenario_collection (id, date_collected, file_name, scenarioid) VALUES (137, '2014-10-16 14:47:00', '20141016134500-eland.log', 11);
```

So try using single quotes

Answer (score 0):

You can set the values through parameters, so the value will not be interpreted as control code! You can find a good explanation [here](http://www.mkyong.com/hibernate/hibernate-parameter-binding-examples/)

```
String hql = "from Stock s where s.stockCode = :stockCode";
List result = session.createQuery(hql)
.setParameter("stockCode", "7277")
.list();
```

Answer (score -2):

I'm wondered if your date1 & date2 is string? If not, please give date parameter instead.